Raspi 4 Bookworm GPIO Issues using GPIOZero
I haven't work with the Raspberry Pi for a long time.
I have an old Raspberry Pi 4 and I installed the latest bookworm OS.
pi@raspi4:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

I loaded a very simple script like this using gpiozero
from gpiozero import Device, LED

led = LED(18)

But I am getting this error
/home/pi/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:300: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from lgpio: No module named 'lgpio'
  warnings.warn(
/home/pi/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:300: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: No module named 'RPi'
  warnings.warn(
/home/pi/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:300: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from pigpio: No module named 'pigpio'
  warnings.warn(
/home/pi/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:297: NativePinFactoryFallback: Falling back to the experimental pin factory NativeFactory because no other pin factory could be loaded. For best results, install RPi.GPIO or pigpio. See https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_pins.html for more information.
  warnings.warn(NativePinFactoryFallback(native_fallback_message))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/native.py", line 237, in export
    result = self._exports[pin]
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 18

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/native.py", line 247, in export
    result = os.open(self.path_value(pin),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value'

I have read somewhere that only Raspi 5 have some issues with GPIO libraries but why am I having this problem also on a Raspi 4?
Any hints on how to make this work?

I am using virtual environment and executed "pip install gpiozero". Will I need to execute "pip install lgpio" also?

I did a "pip freeze" outside the virtual environment and found the following versions of the libraries "gpiozero==2.0 lgpio==0.2.2.0".  If I have not used Virtual Environment then it should work out of the box. I did not bother to update my Raspberry Pi Packages though. I am very used to using Virtual Environments though. So nothing is wrong if I just add the lgpio in my requirements.txt right? Thanks very much for your pointers though.

Thank you very much again for your help.

gpiozero should already be included in Bookworm. You should ensure it is the latest version which has been updated to use lgpio as pinfactory which will work on all Pi.
You should NOT install system packages with pip but use apt which ensures all dependencies are installed and will be updated as part of the normal update process.
Extract from the gpiozero documentation:-

GPIO Zero is packaged in the apt repositories of Raspberry Pi OS, Debian and Ubuntu. It is also available on PyPI.
First, update your repositories list:
sudo apt update
Then install the package for Python 3:
sudo apt install python3-gpiozero


If you NEED to install any packages using pip ensure your venv is created with system packages. E.g. mkdir env && cd env && python -m venv --system-site-packages env

Thank you very much for your insights. I have not used the option --system-site-packages so I did some reading about this.  Some say that this is not a good option to use as it compromises the isolation that virtual environments are intended to provide.  I am also unsure about this as I have not used this option. What do you think?

@MarkEstrada it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If your code depends on a package it will use the system package UNLESS YOU INSTALL a different version into your env; nothing is compromised. Your question does not indicate any reason for a venv, but if you want to install all the dependencies that is OK. Indeed you have not indicated any reason to use a venv as Bookworm should include gpiozero  2.0. If I am doing something which would conflict with the system e.g. use a different version of python or building a wheel I don't use --system-site-packages

Great. Thanks to the both of you. I learned a lot of stuff from your insights.
